# The mod_rewrite problem

Tags: discussion, migration

ServerFault has been a very popular place to ask mod_rewrite questions. We get [a lot of them](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite). I'm not an apache guru so I can't speak to how we'll they've been answered, but it has struck a couple of us that ProWebmasters would be a better place for some of them. Getting some of them moved over here may increase visibility of Webmasters, which is not a bad thing.

I suspect a good number of the mod_rewrite questions we get would get better service over here.

Some example questions:

1. [mod-rewrite sub-domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/193874/mod-rewrite-sub-domains) -- Question history suggests he is more of a web-tech person, but the question itself is (to my mind at least) fairly technical for mod_rewrite.
2. [Apache URL rewrite for subdomain pointing to an existing virtual server resource?](https://serverfault.com/questions/192095/apache-url-rewrite-for-subdomain-pointing-to-an-existing-virtual-server-resource) -- Obviously new user to SF, but getting mixed up in some basic mod_rewrite stuff.
3. [mod_rewrite: redirect from subdomain to main domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/189684/mod-rewrite-redirect-from-subdomain-to-main-domain) -- Another variation on the topic of serving multiple domains from a single directory. Also, another brand new user to SF.
4. [Apache, Mod_Rewrite, .htaccess, Rewrite urls behind mod_proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/187841/apache-mod-rewrite-htaccess-rewrite-urls-behind-mod-proxy) -- An unanswered question from a user whose question history suggests they do a lot of webmastering.
5. [Broken .htaccess](https://serverfault.com/questions/187735/broken-htaccess) -- mod_rewrite in .htaccess.

You know your userbase far, far better than we do. I don't want us moving stuff that's inappropriate. Perhaps it's too low level for here, and that's OK. Or maybe you WANT this traffic. Do any of these questions belong here?

Comment: Based on my experience most the people on ProWebmasters do not appear to be systems people, more SEO, HTML, etc. Believe I've even asked web systems questions, been told it's not the right place, and deleted the question myself. ServerFault is far better at answering backend web systems questions. (That said, I agree, and have found it confusing that mod_rewrite would not be on ProWebmasters.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *How?* question on rewrites feels like it should be a ServerFault thing, whereas a *Why?* question might belong at Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I'd move them en masse, since the topic is pretty relevant to both sites. However, my impression of this site is that it is used more for questions regarding front-end type stuff. `mod_rewrite` is more of a behind the scenes kind of thing, and might be more relevant to SF, particularly since it is related to a web server.

Comment: There is push to move some of this stuff over here as it is seen as on the other side of the edge between our two domains. However, figuring out where the edge sits is *exactly* what the meta sites are all about.

Answer (score 2):

A good example of a question belonging more to webmasters than serverfault

[How to track referrals in Google Analytics when mod_rewrite is used with R=301](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4665)

(I changed the link to have a better title, since I cannot change the title directly, yet)