# Apache Server related questions?

Tags: discussion

I know there is a precedent for [mod_rewrite](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/the-mod-rewrite-problem) to be acceptable on webmasters.

Are discussions about setup of conf files germane and adhere to the on-topic standards?

This well-formed question one [caught my eye](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16223/macosx-virtualhost-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-error):

> The Apache instalation of MacOSX is running Ok.
>
> I have tried to create a VirtualHost called test.local, but as soon as
>   I uncomment from /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf the line
>
> Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf , and try to
>   access test.local virtualhost I get an error "You don't have
>   permission to access / on this server".
>
> The VirtualHost configuration in
>   /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is:
>
> ServerName test.local   DocumentRoot
>   "/Users/username/Sites/Test/public"   
>       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
>       AllowOverride All
>       Order allow,deny
>       Allow from all     I have also include
>   the VirtualHost in hosts file:
>
> 127.0.0.1 test.local

IMHO, I feel these more technical questions are best suited for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com), or [Stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com).

There's also [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/how-to-configure-virtual-host-to-consider-domain-path-in-apache)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer to [The mod_rewrite](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/the-mod-rewrite-problem) problem still seems like the logical way to delineate (if I do say so myself) but, as you have noted from the [How to configure virtual host to consider domain path in Apache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/how-to-configure-virtual-host-to-consider-domain-path-in-apache) question, some of the mods and voters at StackOverflow haven't gotten the memo yet.

For questions like the one you linked, please use the flagging feature to get a moderator's attention.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of delineating could be:

If the webserver is up and running and you're tweaking configuration, then it's Webmasters.

If it's not running properly then it's Serverfault.